# Socketcan register listener isn't called

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, can-bus, socketcan

I am using Meteor with 'socketcan' npm package on a RaspberryPi. To define my CAN network, I am using a kayak file 'canDefinition.kcd'. This is what my startup javascript file in the server folder looks like:

```js
// This code is running OUTSIDE of Meteor.startup loop

"use strict";
var can = Meteor.npmRequire('socketcan');
var fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs');

// Parse database
var network = can.parseNetworkDescription("/home/MyMeteorProject/public/canDefinition.kcd");
var channel = can.createRawChannel("can0");
var db      = new can.DatabaseService(channel, network.buses["Private"]);

channel.start();


db.messages["x192_speed"].signals["motor"].onChange(function(s) {
    var newValue = s.value[1] * 256 + s.value[0];
    console.log("onChange successful" + newValue);
});
```

I followed the instructions of [sebi2k1/node-can](https://github.com/sebi2k1/node-can).

**The problem** is now, that the listener 'onChange' isn't called when the selected CAN message is arriving.

What is already working/ what I already checked:

- Receiving a specific CAN message by filtering the id (see code below)
- Accessing/reading the canDefiniton.kcd database

```js
// This code is running in Meteor.startup loop

var old_value = 0;
    //CAN bus test:
    var boundFunction = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (msg) {
        if (msg.id == 0x192)
        {
            console.log(msg.data);
            var Value = msg.data[0];
            mCollection.update({Name: 'motor'}, {$set: {Value: Value}});


        }
        old_value = Value;
    });
    // Log any message
    channel.addListener("onMessage", boundFunction );
```

Someone helps? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Current state:

I receive some CAN messages, but not all. It looks like that my kcd file was in a slightly wrong format. Now I got it working, but just partly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<NetworkDefinition xmlns="http://kayak.2codeornot2code.org/1.0">
    <Document name="CANDatabase.dbc" date="Mon Jul 13 08:46:25 UTC 2016">Converted with CANBabel (https://github.com/julietkilo/CANBabel)</Document>
    <Node id="Vector__XXX" name="Vector__XXX"/>
    <Bus name="Machine">
        <Message id="0x219" name="x219_Diagnose_Interface" length="8">
            <Signal name="hw_start" offset="32"/>
            <Signal name="hw_Valid" offset="35"/>
            <Signal name="hw_Stickcheck" offset="36"/>
            <Signal name="hw_TT_On" offset="33"/>
        </Message>
        <Message id="0x128" name="x128_hw_Istwerte" length="8">
            <Multiplex length="4" name="x195_hw_Currentvalue_Mux" offset="0">
                <MuxGroup count="1">
                    <Signal name="Wire_Stick1" offset="6"/>
                    <Signal name="ready" offset="21"/>
                    <Signal length="16" name="Current" offset="48">
                        <Value slope="0.1" unit="A" max="6553.5"/>
                    </Signal>
                    <Signal name="E01" offset="17"/>
                    <Signal length="16" name="Tension" offset="32">
                        <Value slope="0.1" unit="V" max="6553.5"/>
                    </Signal>
                    <Signal name="E03" offset="19"/>
                    <Signal name="PU_ready" offset="8"/>
                    <Signal name="E04" offset="18"/>
                    <Signal name="Current_running" offset="5"/>
                    <Signal name="E25" offset="16"/>
                </MuxGroup>
                <MuxGroup count="4">
                    <Signal name="Wire_Stick4" offset="6"/>
                    <Signal name="PU_ready4" offset="8"/>
                    <Signal name="Current_running4" offset="5"/>
                    <Signal length="16" name="Current_Power" offset="32">
                        <Value unit="W" max="65535.0"/>
                    </Signal>
                </MuxGroup>
            </Multiplex>
        </Message>
```

If I only call a muxed message, e.g. id **0x128** signal **ready** than nothing happens. I don't get a callback.

If I only call a "normal" message, e.g. id **0x219** signal **hw_start** it works fine and i receive the correct value.

If I call both together with two different onchangeListener, it is NOT working!
I already checked, if I sent some wrong messages, but I they were all correct. After the doc, [sebi2k1/node-can](https://github.com/sebi2k1/node-can) is able to handle muxed messages!

Maybe this can help someone that don't uses muxed messages. I keep on trying on the muxed ones.